# jBPM Simulation Compilation Errors after Clean Install

Tags: jbpm

After installing jBPM 6.4 using the installer on Windows, when I model a simple process and try to run the simulation I get the errors below. I get the same errors when trying to run simulation on the included sample processes as well. Thoughts?

> 2016-06-03 13:13:05,878 ERROR [org.jbpm.designer.web.server.SimulationServlet] (default task-48) Error during simulation: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while building knowledge base: Unable to generate rule invoker. : [Accumulate: input=[AND [[Pattern: id=null; objectType=ActivitySimulationEvent]] ]]
>       simulation/Rule_Calculate_average_duration_for_activity912964658AccumulateExpression2Invoker.java (19:831) : Cannot cast from long to Long
>       simulation/Rule_Calculate_average_duration_for_activity912964658AccumulateExpression2Invoker.java (19:831) : Type mismatch: cannot convert from Long to long
>
> ### ...
>
> Unable to generate rule invoker. : [Accumulate: input=[AND [[Pattern: id=null; objectType=HTAggregatedSimulationEvent]] ]]
>       simulation/Rule_Calculate_human_activity_summary927771080AccumulateExpression3Invoker.java (19:834) : Cannot cast from double to Double
>   etc.
>
> ### ...
>
> Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='Calculate activity summary']
>       simulation/Rule_Calculate_activity_summary1795396102.java (43:3092) : The constructor AggregatedActivitySimulationEvent(String, String, Double, Double, Double, long, String) is undefined
>
> ### ...
>
> Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='Calculate end event summary']
>       simulation/Rule_Calculate_end_event_summary1338519770.java (43:3124) : The constructor AggregatedEndEventSimulationEvent(String, String, Double, Double, Double, long, String) is undefined
>
> ### ...
>
> at org.jbpm.simulation.impl.WorkingMemorySimulationRepository.(WorkingMemorySimulationRepository.java:58) [jbpm-simulation-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
>       at org.jbpm.simulation.SimulationRunner.runSimulation(SimulationRunner.java:78) [jbpm-simulation-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
>       at org.jbpm.simulation.SimulationRunner.runSimulation(SimulationRunner.java:73) [jbpm-simulation-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]

The logs go on for a bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Java8 with Wildfly 8.2.1?  There is a known issue that the ejc (eclipse java compiler) jar included in that version of Wildfly is NOT recognising Java8 correctly, and is therefore falling back to Java 1.5 (where auto-casting of Long to long isn't supported).

There are several options, but the easiest one is probably to force java compiler level yourself, set system property 'drools.dialect.java.compiler' to '1.8'.  Other options would be to use Janino instead of ejc, or upgrade te ejc version.

Comment: Thanks Kris. In which file should `drools.dialect.java.compiler` be set?